# Hosting webhook target GCP Cloud Function

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, cloud

I am very new to GCP, my plan is create a webhook target on GCP to listen for events on a thirdparty application, kick off scripts to download files from webhook event and push to JIRA/Github. During my research read alot about cloud functions, but there were also cloud run, app engine and PubSub. Any suggestions on which path to follow?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are use cases in which Cloud Functions, Cloud Run and App Engine can be used indistinctively (not Pubsub as it is a messaging service). There are however use cases that do not fit some of them properly.

CloudFunctions must be triggered and each execution is (should be) isolated, that implies you can not expect it to keep a connection alive to your third party. Also they have limited time per execution. They tend to be atomic in a way that if you have complex logic between them you must be careful in your design otherwise you will end with a very difficult to manage distributed solution.

App Engine is an application you deploy and it is permanently active, therefore you can mantain a connection to your third party app.

Cloud Run is somewhere in the middle, being triggered when is used but it can share a context and different requests benefit from that (keeping alive connections temporarily or caching, for instance). It also has more capabilities in terms of technologies you can use.

PubSub, as mentioned, is a service where you can send information (fire and forget) and allows you to have one or more listeners on the other side that may be your Cloud Function, App Engine or Cloud Run to process the information and proceed.

BTW consider using Cloud Storage for your files, specially if you expect to be there between different service calls.